# AWS Chalice route working locally, but not when deployed

Tags: python, chalice

I'm new to AWS Chalice and I'm running into obstacles during deployment--essentially, everything works fine when I run `chalice local`, I can go to the route I've defined and it will return the related JSON data. However, once deployed and I try accessing the same route, I get the HTTP 502 Bad Gateway error:

```
{
    "message": "Internal server error"
}
```

Is there something I'm missing when I set up my AWS IAM roles? Or, more generally, is there some level of configuration with AWS beyond just setting a config file with the access key and secret in the .aws directory on my system? Below is the basic boilerplate code I'm running when I get the error:

```
from chalice import Chalice
import json, datetime, os
from chalicelib import config

app = Chalice(app_name='trading-bot')
app.debug = True


@app.route('/quote')
def quote():
    return {"hello": "world"}
```

Please let me know if there's any more details I can provide; again I'm new to Chalice and AWS in general so it may be some simple settings I need to update on my profile.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add the logs from cloudwatch logs: /aws/lambda/trading-bot-{stage} ?